# Getting Connection-State from Bluetooth Low Energy Device from Device Manager

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy

i'm developing on a Bluetooth Low Energy Device and i need to see in code if the device is connected or not.
First thing i noticed was that there is in the Devicemanager a Attribute "Verbunden"-> English: Connected and it says true or false if my device is connected or not. So i need to read that Attribute in my program.

What i have tried till now:

Getting all Devices with SetupDiGetClassDevs
Getting the FriendlyName with SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty
Searching for my Device with the name.
That works.

Now i wanted to get that Connected-Attribute but i didn't find out what i have to use at SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty.

SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty is described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551967(v=vs.85).aspx

Maybe someone knows what is the right value for Property.

My Code:

```
int get_device_info( void )
{
   HDEVINFO hDevInfo;
   SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData;
   DWORD i;
   FILE *   devices = fopen("devices.txt", "a+");
   GUID AGuid;
   //GUID can be constructed from "{xxx....}" string using CLSID
   CLSIDFromString(TEXT(TO_SEARCH_DEVICE_UUID), &AGuid);
   GUID BluetoothInterfaceGUID = AGuid;

   // Create a HDEVINFO with all present devices.
   hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&BluetoothInterfaceGUID,
       0, // Enumerator
       0,
       DIGCF_ALLCLASSES | DIGCF_PRESENT);

   if (hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
       // Insert error handling here.
       return 1;
   }

   // Enumerate through all devices in Set.
   DeviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);
   for (i=0;SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo,i,
       &DeviceInfoData);i++)
   {
       DWORD DataT;
       LPTSTR buffer = NULL;
       DWORD buffersize = 0;

       //
       // Call function with null to begin with,
       // then use the returned buffer size (doubled)
       // to Alloc the buffer. Keep calling until
       // success or an unknown failure.
       //
       //  Double the returned buffersize to correct
       //  for underlying legacy CM functions that
       //  return an incorrect buffersize value on
       //  DBCS/MBCS systems.
       //
       while (!SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
           hDevInfo,
           &DeviceInfoData,
           SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME,
           //SPDRP_DEVICEDESC,
           //SPDRP_CAPABILITIES,
           &DataT,
           (PBYTE)buffer,
           buffersize,
           &buffersize))
       {
           if (GetLastError() ==
               ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
           {
               // Change the buffer size.
               if (buffer) LocalFree(buffer);
               // Double the size to avoid problems on
               // W2k MBCS systems per KB 888609.
               buffer = (wchar_t *)LocalAlloc(LPTR,buffersize * 2);
           }
           else
           {
               // Insert error handling here.
               break;
           }
       }
       if(buffer)
       {

       if( strcmp("Name of Device",AnsiString(buffer).c_str())==0)
       {
       fprintf(devices,"Result:[%s]",AnsiString(buffer).c_str());

       if (buffer) LocalFree(buffer);
       }
       }

   }


   if ( GetLastError()!=NO_ERROR &&
        GetLastError()!=ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS )
   {
       // Insert error handling here.
       return 1;
   }

   //  Cleanup
   SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);
    fclose(devices);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out a solution.

```
GUID AGuid;
    //GUID can be constructed from "{xxx....}" string using CLSID
   CLSIDFromString(TEXT(TO_SEARCH_DEVICE_UUID), &AGuid);
   GUID BluetoothInterfaceGUID = AGuid;
   // Create a HDEVINFO with all present devices.
   hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&BluetoothInterfaceGUID,
       0, // Enumerator
       0,
       DIGCF_ALLCLASSES | DIGCF_PRESENT);//DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT);//DIGCF_ALLCLASSES | DIGCF_PRESENT);

   if (hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
       // Insert error handling here.
       return 1;
   }


   // Enumerate through all devices in Set.

   DeviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);
   for (i=0;SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo,i,
       &DeviceInfoData);i++)
   {
       DWORD DataT;
       LPTSTR buffer = NULL;
       LPTSTR buffer1 = NULL;
       DWORD buffersize = 0;

       while (!SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty( // Get Name
           hDevInfo,
           &DeviceInfoData,
           SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME,
           &DataT,
           (PBYTE)buffer,
           buffersize,
           &buffersize))
       {
           if (GetLastError() ==
               ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
           {
               // Change the buffer size.
               if (buffer) LocalFree(buffer);
               // Double the size to avoid problems on
               // W2k MBCS systems per KB 888609.
               buffer = (wchar_t *)LocalAlloc(LPTR,buffersize * 2);
           }
           else
           {
               // Insert error handling here.
               break;
           }
       }
        {

       if(strcmp("Your Device",AnsiString(buffer).c_str())==0)  //Found your device
       {

        //########
       DEVPROPTYPE ulPropertyType;
       DWORD dwSize;
       ULONG devst;

//     memset(devst,0,sizeof(devst));
       bool err = SetupDiGetDeviceProperty(   //Checking Connection State
            hDevInfo,
            &DeviceInfoData,
            &DEVPKEY_Device_DevNodeStatus,   //Connected(0x02000000)
            &ulPropertyType,
            (BYTE *) &devst,
            sizeof(devst),
            &dwSize,
            0);
       DWORD error;
       error = GetLastError();



        if (devst &0x02000000) {
            //"Status: Getrennt "

        }
        else
        {
            //"Status: Verbunden"

        }
```

Hope this snippet helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo, you would try:
1. using SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces
2. using SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceProperty
3. using SetupDiGetDeviceInterfacePropertyKeys to get a list of all Property Keys available for the interface
4. using SetupDiGetDeviceProperty and/or SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty

Instead of using SPDRP_XXX constants, you would use DEVPROP, as defined in 'devpkey.h' ...
Below are a few examples taken from the log of a test prog I wrote to discover the whole thing:

```
    DEVPROPNAME: DEVPKEY_DeviceInterface_Bluetooth_DeviceAddress
    DEVPROPGUID: {2BD67D8B-8BEB-48D5-87E0-6CDA3428040A}
    DEVPROPPID: 1
    DEVPROPTYPE: DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING
    Value: c026df001017
   DEVPROPNAME: DEVPKEY_Device_Children
   DEVPROPGUID: {4340A6C5-93FA-4706-972C-7B648008A5A7}
   DEVPROPPID: 9
   DEVPROPTYPE: DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING_LIST
   Value:
BTHLEDevice\{00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_c026df001017\8&2fd07168&1&0001
BTHLEDevice\{00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_c026df001017\8&2fd07168&1&0008
BTHLEDevice\{00001809-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_c026df001017\8&2fd07168&1&000c
BTHLEDevice\{0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_c026df001017\8&2fd07168&1&0010
BTHLEDevice\{0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_c026df001017\8&2fd07168&1&0014
BTHLEDevice\{00001523-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123}_c026df001017\8&2fd07168&1&0019
```

On a second subject, you are 'working' on the 'device' itself ( SetupDiGetClassDevs(&BluetoothInterfaceGUID...) [and then working on the \BTHLE\ tree in Registry].
After listing all GattServices of this device and getting their uuids, you could restart that iteration on the device_guid itself SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GattServiceGUID...) [and then working on the \BTHLEDevice\ tree in Registry].

Now, to answer your question, I'm still searching myself :) But I'm not really sure:
1) that it is a working (dynamic) information to know the connection state
2) that it is a 'Property' you can access by the above methods